# Probability Sum in R

Tags: r, probability

I'm trying to run some probability codes in R without using the dice package. I know that when there are two vectors, it's possible to use the outer command to generate a matrix that will calculate the sums and values for the dice rolls. Is there anything similar to that which can do the same thing for five dice rolls?

I'm working on rolling five six-sided dice in R and generating a code to calculate the probability of getting between 15 and 20 for the sum of the rolls.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Please provide some code.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein, I was just wondering if there was an easier way to do it without writing loops, as in the outer command for two vectors. Otherwise, what I have is just getting the individual probabilities for the five dice, adding them, and finding the probability that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always just do it by simulation:

```
set.seed(1020)
nn<-1e6 #number simulations
#on each simulation, check whether the sum of 5
#  independently rolled (6-sided) dice is less
#  than 2.5 away from 17.5--equivalently, that
#  the sum is between 15 & 20; the probability
#  is the percentage of the time that this happens,
#  or equivalently, the mean of the indicator function
> mean(replicate(nn,abs(sum(sample(6,5,T))-17.5)<=2.5))
[1] 0.556971
```

The actual solution is 4332/7776=.5570988, which can be found with this (inefficient, but who cares because 6^5=7776) loop:

```
tot<-0L
for (i1 in 1:6){
  for (i2 in 1:6){
    for (i3 in 1:6){
      for (i4 in 1:6){
        for (i5 in 1:6){
          s<-i1+i2+i3+i4+i5
          tot<-tot+(s>=15&s<=20)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
> tot/6^5
[1] 0.5570988
```

Answer (score 2):

You could recursively apply `outer`, first computing the sum of 2 dice, then the sum of those results with a 3rd die, then ...

But more efficient would probably be to use `expand.grid` in this case:

```
> dice <- expand.grid( 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6, 1:6 )
> dice.sums <- rowSums(dice)
> mean( 15 <= dice.sums & dice.sums <= 20 )
[1] 0.5570988
```

You could also use the `hcube` function from the combinat package to generate the combinations.

Comment: beautiful usage of `expand.grid`. Could also do this in one line, but this is good for explication.